# Webmatrix thinks i'm my alt on github

Tags: git, github, webmatrix

```
    remote: Permission to CENSORED/CENSORED.git denied to cpmoderator12345.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CENSORED/CENSORED.git': The requested URL returned error: 403
git returned error code 128.

GitSCCProvider.GitCommandLineException: remote: Permission to CENSORED.git denied to cpmoderator12345.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CENSORED': The requested URL returned error: 403
git returned error code 128.
   at GitSCCProvider.GitCommandLine.GitProcessRunInvoked(GitProcessTracker gitProcessTracker)
   at GitSCCProvider.GitCommandLine.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GitAsyncCommandLineExecute>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Anyway, that was the error.
I'm currently signed in GitHub and in GitHub Desktop as my main account, but WebMatrix seems to think im my alt. I've seen the SSH keys and none of them are causing the problem.

I tried using SSH instead of HTTPS on WebMatrix. It didn't work either. Right now I just use the old command line, but I can easily mess things up.

Also, I should have said this first. I am not the owner of the current repository im pushing to, on either of my accounts. But on my main account, I am a collaborator, and the repository is for collaborators only.

Comment: If your main account is a collaborator, using that account (https or ssh) should work. For ssh, you would need your public key registered on that repo as a collaborator.

Answer (score 1):

> I've seen the SSH keys and none of them are causing the problem

Using ssh would be a good idea in order to establish your identity and validate the access to your GitHub repo.

But your are not using an ssh url (`git@github.com:username/reponame`).
From the error message, you are using an https one. Make sure to change that url, and you will benefit from ssh automatic authentication.